# How to prevent dead timed out while scraping data using JSOUP java?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, proxy, jsoup

I learn how to scraping data from a web using jsoup java, in the first try i'm successfully to get the output, but when I try to run again, it gives an error message. Here is my code

```
package solution;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class WebScraper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document d=Jsoup.connect("https://www.wikihow.com/wikiHowTo?search=adjust+bass+on+computerr").timeout(6000).get();
        Elements ele=d.select("div#searchresults_list");
        for (Element element : ele.select("div.result")) {
            String img_url=element.select("div.result_title").text();
            System.out.println(img_url);
        }

    }
}
```

Here are the message error that I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:466)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:460)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:159)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1198)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1107)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:400)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:372)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:587)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:732)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:286)
    at solution.WebScraper.main(WebScraper.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone can help ?

P.S edit:

After solved this issue, there are several solutions approach to this problem such as:

1. give a higher value in timeout parameter, e.g the time set to 8000 (before 6000)
2. make sure your internet connection is stable

thanks for everyone who has give advices for this problem

Comment: Well, you have set a `timeout(6000)`, which is 6 seconds... (`6,000 milliseconds`), did you try setting that higher?  I mean, if you set a `timeout` and get a timeout exception... :)

Comment: Also, some web-servers have all kinds of security code which prevents scrapers from hitting the same site over and over again.  Maybe the server is ***intentionally*** inserting a ***delay***... Could be?

Comment: Nice answer setting the timeout with a higher value, it really helpful thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly your internet connection speed is very low.
Check your Internet connection.

Or try the url on the browser. Check how much time it takes to load the html.

Also, add a try-catch block.

Comment: Hmm good solution, i 've try to change my connection and it's work, thanks for the advice :D

Answer (score 2):

Some observations:

1. The stacktrace shows that the timeout occurred while the client is still going through the SSL setup.  There are a few things that can go wrong in that process.
2. The `timeout(6000)` is setting the timeout to 6 seconds.  That is pretty short ... if the network path is congested, the server is a long way away, the server is heavily loaded and so on.
3. You said it worked to start with and stopped working.  This could be a load or congestion issue.  Or the server might have seen *repeated calls* from your client asking for the same URL, and interpreted it as a DOS attack or a misconfigured application ... and put a block on your IP address.